# Magento product added from admin slowly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I am saving a list of products via admin interface. Every time i enter a product, it takes a lots of time loading.

Is there any solution to this problem ? Is there any extension that accelarate the process of saving ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add new and update the existing products in your store, then [Magmi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) is the quickest solution. You may face the lack of good interface, but you can save all data in csv and then load it using Magmi very fast.

If this solution doesn't suits you, I'll recommend you to read the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028604/few-tips-how-to-speed-up-saving-product-in-magento), where a good response has been given:

> Just set Index mode to "Manual" for all indexes.
>   So magento won't run reindex after every product save.
>   Don't forget to set them back to normal and run full reindex after product import is finished.